# Having some trouble with a 'continue' and 'break' error in my code

Tags: python, loops, break, continue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8FBE.png)okay so this a question on quiz I am taking currently. **I don't want to know the answer** I just want to know why I keep getting an error when I try to use break or continue in my loop. Is it a syntax thing or did I just format my loop wrong? Again **no spoilers** just want some guidance so I can get past this. thanks for any and all feedback

here is my code:

[image: code]

Comment: `print(', '.join(map(str, range(0,100,7))))` ;)

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory; you use `continue` outside a loop, and `continue` can't be used outside of a loop.

Comment: It isn't clear what `else: continue` is supposed to do.

Comment: you cannot use `result != float`, this will always be `False`, instead check the result of the division, `14%7 == 0` -> `True`

Comment: @mozway: The OP did was explicit about **not** wanting the answer to the quiz. Shouldn't you respect that?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin this was not a serious answer, OP wants to use a loop ;)

Comment: @SylvesterKruin OP's instructor would likely not accept that as an answer, or approve of trying to get help on Stack Overflow in the middle of a quiz

Comment: thank you for all your guys quick responses it helped me look at my problem differently. I changed my code a little to get the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The continue function cannot be used unless it is in a loop, and you currently do not have a loop. Loops are typically created with "for" or "while".

Using "for" or "while" would help you immensely, especially since your current code wouldn't check the numbers from zero to 100, but rather just the number 100.

I recommend using or researching the modulo(%) operator, as that would work well in this situation.

If you really get stuck, here is a solution to the problem, along with an explanation for what each line is doing:
[solution](https://i.imgur.com/qKzJtw4.png)
It is not the smallest way possible, but it's the way I prefer.